# About 'is' and 'are' using numbers

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct English; "one and one is two" or "one and one are two"?

Likewise for "two and three is five" or "two and three are five"?

Comment: You can use both. In mathematis "is (equal to)" is preferred. But two apples and three apples are five apples is also logical.